# Statistics uniform distribution commuter bus

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, means

> > The time, $X$, it takes a commuter bus to complete its route is uniformly distributed between 85 and 109 minutes.
> >
> > $e)$ What is the probability the bus takes less than 90 or more than 95 minutes to complete the route?

---

I have done the following

$f(x) = \frac{1}{109-85} = \frac{1}{24}$

In order to find for the probability for more than 95 minutes to complete the route, I did the following for the uniform distribution

$P(x > 95) = (109 - 95) * 1/24 = 0.583333$

$P(x < 90) = (90 - 85) * \frac{1}{24} = 0.2083333 \ldots$

Do I just add $0.583333 \ldots + 0.2083333\ldots?$

Comment: Well done!  You're doing well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes exactly that. For precision I would add them before rounding i.e.

$$ \frac{14}{24} + \frac{5}{24} = \frac{19}{24} \approx 0.79166 \ldots$$